# using xargs bash command with spaces is possible?

Tags: unix, args

Here is my current command which i use:

```
xargs -n 1 -P 250 php b <targets
```

It is possible to using this command like that:

```
xargs -n 1 -P 250 php b <targets [SOMETHINGELE]
```

I mean the machine to execute like that:

```
php b %target% %something else value%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-I` option to specify a placeholder in the command where the input should be substituted:

```
xargs -P 250 -I {} php b {} 'something else' < targets
```

You don't need `-n 1` when you use this, as it automatically processes just one input per command line.

Comment: great it works, thanks, i will accept your answer soon i can.